# In R: Subset observations that have values, 0, 1, and 2 by group

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have the following data:

```
companyID   status
    1         1
    1         1
    1         0
    1         2
    2         1
    2         1
    2         1
    3         1
    3         0
    3         2
    3         2
    3         2
```

And would like to subset those observations (by companyID) where status has 0, 1, and 2 across the group (companyID). My preferred outcome would look like the following:

```
companyID   status
    1         1
    1         1
    1         0
    1         2
    3         1
    3         0
    3         2
    3         2
    3         2
```

Thank you in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select groups where all the values from 0-2 are present in the group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(companyID) %>%filter(all(0:2 %in% status))

#  companyID status
#      <int>  <int>
#1         1      1
#2         1      1
#3         1      0
#4         1      2
#5         3      1
#6         3      0
#7         3      2
#8         3      2
#9         3      2
```

In base R and data.table :

```
#Base R : 
subset(df, as.logical(ave(status, companyID, FUN = function(x) all(0:2 %in% x))))

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(0:2 %in% status)], companyID]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
       group_by(companyID) %>%
       filter(sum(0:2 %in% status) == 3)
```